# Is tsconfig's `baseUrl` property still safe to use?

Tags: node.js, typescript, tsconfig

I'm currently running a node.js application in typescript where all my imports are relative like:

```js
import { compare } from '../../helpers/compare';
```

and I would like to transform them to:

```js
import { compare } from 'helpers/compare';
```

I know I could just add the `baseUrl` property in my `tsconfig.json` to `"./src"`, but looking at [the official documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#baseUrl) the last paragraph say:

> This feature was designed for use in conjunction with AMD module loaders in the browser, and is not recommended in any other context. As of TypeScript 4.1, baseUrl is no longer required to be set when using paths.

Does it mean the [`baseUrl`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#baseUrl) shouldn't be used anymore ? does this means it would be preferable to use the [`paths`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#paths) property instead ? (and then aliases all my import ?)

(I'm currently using TypeScript 5.2).

Comment: "not recommended in any other context" - Yes